# Como puedo detectar que tipo de dato se está entregando en la consola? c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

como puedo hacer, que la variable “txt” detecte que tipo de datos esta entregando?

```
public string txt;
public void Main(){
Console.WriteLine(“Hola Mundo”);
txt = Console.ReadLine();

if(txt ==  “string”){
// Ejecutar alguna acción si es string
}
if(txt == “int”){
 // Ejecutar una acción si es int
 }
if(txt == “float”){
// Ejecutar una acción si es float
}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dado que el `Console.ReadLine()` va a obtener siempre un `String`:

> public static **string** ReadLine ();

Lo que debes hacer es jugar con los `TryParse` ([+info](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.byte.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Byte_TryParse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_IFormatProvider_System_Byte__)) de los diferentes tipos desados:

```
var txt = Console.ReadLine();
decimal decParsed;
int intParsed;            

if (int.TryParse(txt, out intParsed))
    Console.WriteLine("Es un entero: " + intParsed);
else if (decimal.TryParse(txt, out decParsed))
    Console.WriteLine("Es un decimal: " + decParsed);
else Console.WriteLine("Es un string: " + txt);

Console.ReadLine();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Como declaraste anteriormente a txt como string siempre será el resultado del string.
Lo que debes hacer es asignar a un tipo var para que lo asigne desde que lo teclea.
Y validar con la porpiedad de GetType()

```
var txt = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (Type.GetTypeCode(txt.GetType()))
        {
            case TypeCode.String:
                // Ejecutar alguna acción si es String
            break;
            case TypeCode.Decimal:
                // Ejecutar alguna acción si es Decimal
            break;
            case TypeCode.Int32:
                // Ejecutar alguna acción si es Int32
            break;
        }
```

Pero para solo mostrar el tipo solo necesitas

```
Console.WriteLine("El tipo de datos es: " + txt.GetType());
```

Comment: Hmm..estas seguro de que ese código funciona? `Console.ReadLine` siempre devuelve un`string`, con lo que da igual que metas por consola, siempre se va a ir en el `switch` a `TypeCode.String`...

Comment: Efectivamente, ese código no funciona porque, como dice Pikoh, el Console.ReadLine siempre va a devolver un string.